# Why are my supported android devices so low?

Tags: android, google-play

Why are my supported android devices so low? I've tried to target the lowest possible apk (13), and yet only 12,000 devices can use my app.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Here is my build.gradle.

```
android {
signingConfigs {
}
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "thomas.surfaceviewtest"
    minSdkVersion 13
    targetSdkVersion 13
    versionCode 5
    versionName "1.0.5"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
    }
}
dexOptions {
}
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.4.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

[image]

Comment: targetSdkVersion 13, why?

Comment: Please post the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: That's a rather high number - the catalogue lists about 14k devices. I'm at about 12700 devices with my app (~100k downloads); And as said, you can set your targetSDK to 25 or 26 (26 being Android O - you might have to change a few things for it to work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because your `target sdk` level is low

```
targetSdkVersion 13
```

Update it to 25 so it will support more devices

```
targetSdkVersion 25
```

You can check for more android sdk version [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platforms.html)

Comment: target and compile. Shouldn't a problem though, it packs the API 23 SDK (see compile) so it shouldn't be a problem

Comment: when u set target sdk 13 it will only target to the mobile which 13 and below but u can install it in more than 13 but it wont display in playstore

Comment: False. Targeting a lower API means it is designed for that platform. Later versions of Android can still use it (without issues) though it may have bugs as a result of targeting an earlier API version. It is like by targeting and compiling against API 23, you can still run it on API 24

Comment: You end up being unable to access material design (if I remember correctly, can't double check that right now) because of the target version, but it doesn't disable 13 versions of Android

Comment: min sdk version Is the earliest release of the Android SDK that your application can run on. Usually this is because of a problem with the earlier APIs, lacking functionality, or some other behavioral issue.

Comment: target sdk version The version your application was targeted to run on. Ideally this is because of some sort of optimal run conditions. If you were to "make your app for version 19" this is where that would be specified. It may run on earlier or later releases, but this is what you were aiming for. This is mostly to indicate how current your application is for use in the marketplace, etc.

Comment: And it **still doesn't disable versions 14-26**. INdicating what the app is designed for doesn't block the other versions from installingæ

Answer (score 5):

That number is comparting your manifest configuration and a list of devices know by Google (see [the list of devices](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1727131?hl=en)).

It is not a number of real devices, but a number of model supported, so 12000 models on the market is a good number I believe.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realise that it meant different makes of devices as opposed to total number of devices (which I was expecting to be in the millions).

Comment: @ThomasPG I am looking for a real definition from their site but can't really find anything about those values. So I can only use the list (see the link) as a source of information.

Answer (score 1):

My app is compatible with 12611 devices. That is basically the same as you have. 12000 devices isn't little, especially given the fact that there are "only" 1465 unsupported devices as a result of my minSdk version being high.

Targeting 12k devices isn't little, it is a lot. If you were only targeting say 8k that would be something you should look into.

You should still change compile and minSdk versions to 25 or 26 (7.1 or 8.0) to make sure your app can run the newest API's.

I'd like to clarify the fact that targeting API 13 doesn't **exclude API 14-26 from installing the app**. It indicates what version it is designed for. You compile against 23 so you have the new API's included, but you only use API 13.

Comment: And 12k devices doesn't mean the amount of devices that can run the app, it means there are 12k different models that can run the app.

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
android:targetSdkVersion
```

An integer designating the API Level that the application targets. If not set, the default value equals that given to `minSdkVersion`.
This attribute informs the system that you have tested against the target version and the system should not enable any compatibility behaviors to maintain your app's forward-compatibility with the target version. The application is still able to run on older versions (down to `minSdkVersion`).

As Android evolves with each new version, some behaviors and even appearances might change. However, if the API level of the platform is higher than the version declared by your app's `targetSdkVersion`, the system may enable compatibility behaviors to ensure that your app continues to work the way you expect. You can disable such compatibility behaviors by specifying `targetSdkVersion` to match the API level of the platform on which it's running. For example, setting this value to "11" or higher allows the system to apply a new default theme (Holo) to your app when running on Android 3.0 or higher and also disables screen compatibility mode when running on larger screens (because support for API level 11 implicitly supports larger screens).

Source: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Answer (score 0):

You should your increase target sdk level.

```
targetSdkVersion 25
```